# ASP.NET MVC4 + SQL Server + LINQ + delete a record after 24 hours

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2012, record

Situation: For a school project I have to build an accommodation website where users can register and make a reservation to a particular accommodation for only 24 hours (after that other users can make a reservation to that accommodation and than they would have an option to that accommodation for 24 hours). How would I trigger an event to delete the record out of the database? Also for doing a reservation you need to click on a link/button to do a POST to my controller.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would opt not to ever delete a reservation record, but rather give it an expiration field.  If a user tries to use a reservation, check whether the expiration field has already expired.

If you must delete the reservation record, I would recommend a separate process.  You could implement a windows service that wakes up periodically and searches for expired reservations to delete, or run a console program that does the same from Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

**In short:** It is always a **good recommended approach** to ***flag*** a record as `IsActive = false` instead of deleting it. This is mostly done to preserver the transaction history.

If you have to delete the records then you may schedule some Windows service to do that job throw services rather than an individual action.